# Eliminar columnas de un dataframe que tengan un % de NAs superior a ''x''

Tags: r, rstudio, dataset

Acabo de iniciarme en el mundo de Rstudio y los dataframes & datasets y me surgen preguntas que a veces no logro responder.

En este caso, tengo un dataset con 640 variables(columnas) y unas 73.000 registros (filas). Lo que quiero es eliminar todas las columnas que tengan un % de NAs superior a un % estimado por mí, por ejemplo, 60%.

Un ejemplo más pequeño podría ser:

```
df <- data.frame(c1=rnorm(100),
                 c2=rnorm(100),
                 c3=rnorm(100),
                 c4=sample(c('A','B','C'),100, replace=TRUE))


# Seteamos NA's en el 61% de los casos de la columna 1 y 3
df[sample(1:100, 100*.61),c(1,3)] <- NA
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es bastante sencillo, edité tu pregunta para dejar un ejemplo mínimo de un `data.frame` que va  funcionar como ejemplo. Lo primero es obtener el porcentaje de `NA` de cada columna, nada más sencillo que hacer:

```
colMeans(is.na(df))

  c1   c2   c3   c4 
0.61 0.00 0.61 0.00
```

Puedes observar que la columna 1 y 3 tiene un porcentaje superior al que deseas. Nota: La media entre valores `1` y `0` (`TRUE` y `FALSE` de `is.na`) te da la proporción de los valores `TRUE` es decir lo que justamente son `NA`.

Luego para borrar las columnas

```
porcentaje <- .6
columnas_a_borrar <- which(colMeans(is.na(df))>porcentaje)
df[,columnas_a_borrar] <- NULL
```

Simplemente creamos un vector `columnas_a_borrar` con aquellos índices de columna que tuvieran un porcentaje mayor de `NA`. Para borra, simplemente asignamos `NULL` a las mismas.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Me ha funcionado perfectamente. Espero que en un tiempo sea yo el sepa solucionar estos problemas tan ''simples''. Un abrazo!